# Some header buttons appear with delay on mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web

On the mobile Stack Overflow website, the Inbox, the Achievements button, etc. appears with some delay after the page has loaded; while the Profile and the Search button shows correctly on time.

So I see this:

[image: Screenshot1: "after page load"]

And then, after a few seconds later it becomes:

[image: Screenshot2: "few seconds later"]

I've expected seeing immediately the second arrangement.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think it is by design. The inbox and achievements are added in later asynchronously. Also, if you immediately click once it is rendered, it [opens your Stack Exchange inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox), and not just the popup. I know that it not a great experience, especially if you are on a slow connection, but I usually wait for around 30 seconds for everything to load.

Comment: @BhargavRao That's strange: i found something: here, on Meta, it works...

Comment: This could just be a delay while content is loaded.  Once it is loaded it will show.  If it is already cached on your device it shows immediately.

Comment: @BhargavRao Ah, so that's the explanation of the "mysterious redirect" I've been experiencing. I thought I misclicked something when I am redirected to the inbox where I would have expected a pop-up. I think that's a bad idea to have different behavior depending on time with no visual feedback.

Comment: @BhargavRao - That is certainly not the way it was designed. No UX dev would think "let's make the page shake as it loads".

Comment: @TravisJ, the UI folks at Stack Overflow are a bit different (like tricking the users to visit a different page when clicking on a few what seem to be pop over menus)  ... so someone might have thought of it this way. We never know.

Comment: It's true that there can be no inferred 100% knowledge. That doesn't mean that it isn't highly likely this was not intended. Also, the UI folks at SO are quite good at what they do, so I would definitely give them the benefit of the doubt here that they didn't intend to make something which appears to be sloppy.