# Top bar reflows after page load, breaking muscle memory

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I don't like web pages that "reflow" (i.e. modify the already visible layout), because when I see an element I'd like to click/touch and it has moved in the (half) second it was visible. See also [Don't let the job recommendations bar loading reflow the activity page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360091/dont-let-the-job-recommendations-bar-loading-reflow-the-activity-page).

It feels like a download site that inserts an advertisement with a green "Download" button, just in place of the site's regular "Download" button.

Demo:

[image: Top Bar Reflow Gif]

The Help and Review icon appear to disappear and collapse into one button, moving the profile icon (which I often click) one spot to the right, causing me to hit the search button instead.

Please don't do this.

For completeness's sake, this happens in Chrome on Android 9, but I can imagine this happens on most mobile browsers.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386330/some-header-buttons-appear-with-delay-on-mobile

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386325/6296561

Comment: Yes! This has really been bugging me lately, it's very offputting.

Comment: Also happened here, I was going to check the inbox (popup) and instead clicked on my profile => I landed on a whole new page, which isn't even responsive... I then have to pinch until these buttons gets accessible and finally be able to access that popup.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386389/review-button-disapears-upon-loading-of-the-screen

Comment: That reminds me of when I visit my profile, I want to tap on the **All actions** tab, and as I do, the **Job Recommendations** panel suddenly expands itself and steals the click.

Comment: To be clear, is this on *initial* page load or when you do some action on the page?

Comment: @TylerH Initial page load. But on mobile browsers, that happens often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has now been fixed using a horizontal scrollbar:

[image: Scrollbar]